# warning: declaration does not declare anything

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting this warning all over the place in some perfectly well functioning objective-c code within XCode. My google-fu has failed me... others have run into this but I could not find an explanation on what exactly is causing it or how it can be fixed.

Comment: Maybe you should provide some example code that induces the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem and fixed it. I had this:

```
enum eventType { singleTouch };
enum eventType type;
```

... and changed it to:

```
enum eventType { singleTouch } type;
```

Comment: I'd guess that the `enum` type declaration was nested in a `struct` declaration and that this is a (C-anti-)pattern you used, that's why you said *“all over the place”*.

Answer (score 3):

In pure C, the following code:

```
int;
typedef int;
```

elicits the following warnings from GCC with no warning options set:

```
x.c:1: warning: useless keyword or type name in empty declaration
x.c:1: warning: empty declaration
x.c:2: warning: useless keyword or type name in empty declaration
x.c:2: warning: empty declaration
```

Maybe you have something analogous in your code?

Answer (score 1):

To add another one to the list since Google brought me here: This warning can also occur with an extraneous "typename" in a using declaration:

```
using SomeType = typename SomeNamespace::SomeType;
```

Where SomeType is not a dependent type.

I got to this scenario after some refactoring to elevate "SomeType" outside of a templated class up to namespace scope to save on memory in an embedded C++ environment. The original implementation:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
    template <typename T>
    SomeClass
    {
    public:
        enum class SomeType
        {
            A,
            B,
        };
        ...
    };
} //namespace SomeNamespace
...
void someFunction()
{
    using SomeType = typename SomeNameSpace::SomeClass<uint8_t>::SomeType;
    //typename is required above to resolve dependent scope
    ...
}
```

I refactored to the following, but forgot to remove the "typename" in someFunction:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
    // Now elevated to namespace scope so it is clear to the compiler that it does
    //    not need to be created for every template type of the class. While most
    //    compilers may be able to figure this one out easily, mine couldn't based
    //    on the optimization settings I need to use for my embedded project.
    enum class SomeType
    {
        A,
        B,
    };

    template <typename T>
    SomeClass
    {
    public:
        ...
    };
} //namespace SomeNamespace
...
void someFunction()
{
    using SomeType = **typename** SomeNameSpace::SomeType;
    //typename is no longer needed, but its removal was missed during refactoring
    ...
}
```

Perhaps some other random traveler will land here and save them 15 minutes of trying to understand the warning's meaning in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this error with the following code:

```
#define MY_INT int;
MY_INT a;
```

It compiles removing the ';' in the #define line.

Comment: How did you compile this? Did you get the exact same wording: *“warning: declaration does not declare anything”*? (this is a *warning* not an *error*)

Comment: @Wolf I am using [this compiler](https://www.godbolt.org/), where you can change compiler, only gcc family gives an error, other just a warning

Comment: @thanks For the quick reply. I was actually interested if you compiled it as C++ or C code. I'm also using gcc to reproduce the message (as warning, maybe you activated  [show warnings as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14933203/2932052)). As commented elsewhere, I reproduce this via type-only declarations (`struct`, `enum`) within `struct` declarations. I think that your specific error/warning should appear with `int;` only.