# Set of Warnings as Error g++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, compiler-warnings

I want to change the behavior of warnings and errors for my g++ compiler:

- I want that normal warnings are spotted as errors (`-Werror`)
- I want extra warnings to be spotted. (`-Wall` and `-Wextra`)

But my problem is that this way, all and extra warning are made errors. Is there a way to achieve what I want without needing to set a long list at `-Werror=xxx,xxx,xxx`. 
Is there some kind of alias for set of errors?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you just give `-Werror` all warnings become errors. Aside from listing the ones you (don't) want to make into errors as `-W(no-)error=xxx`, I don't believe there is a way to "make some warnings into errors".

Of course, one solution might be to compile the code twice - once with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, and once with `-Werror`, but not `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

In the long term, I'm sure it will be worth the extra effort of marking which errors you (don't) want `-Werror` to see as errors [although I'd say the better solution is probably to use -Wno-xxx, to disable any warnings that you deem acceptable, as opposed to "warn but don't make it an error" - after all, the purpose of `-Werror` in my view is to prevent code from being submitted to a project with warnings in it - and that should mean one of two things: the warning is fixed, or the warning is disabled. Whichever makes sense for that project].

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using `-Werror=...` with a long list of warnings you can use `-Werror -Wno-error=...` with a much shorter list of warnings (only the ones enabled by `-Wall -Wextra`). The manual lists which warnings are enabled by `-Wall -Wextra` so it's a no-brainer.